# go 1.8 plugin use custom interface

Tags: go, plugins

I want to use custom interface based on go plugin, but I found it's not support.

#### Definition of filter.Filter

```
package filter

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

// Context filter context
type Context interface {
    SetStartAt(startAt int64)
    SetEndAt(endAt int64)
    GetStartAt() int64
    GetEndAt() int64

    GetProxyServerAddr() string
    GetProxyOuterRequest() *fasthttp.Request
    GetProxyResponse() *fasthttp.Response
    NeedMerge() bool

    GetOriginRequestCtx() *fasthttp.RequestCtx

    GetMaxQPS() int

    ValidateProxyOuterRequest() bool

    InBlacklist(ip string) bool
    InWhitelist(ip string) bool

    IsCircuitOpen() bool
    IsCircuitHalf() bool

    GetOpenToCloseFailureRate() int
    GetHalfTrafficRate() int
    GetHalfToOpenSucceedRate() int
    GetOpenToCloseCollectSeconds() int

    ChangeCircuitStatusToClose()
    ChangeCircuitStatusToOpen()

    RecordMetricsForRequest()
    RecordMetricsForResponse()
    RecordMetricsForFailure()
    RecordMetricsForReject()

    GetRecentlyRequestSuccessedCount(sec int) int
    GetRecentlyRequestCount(sec int) int
    GetRecentlyRequestFailureCount(sec int) int
}

// Filter filter interface
type Filter interface {
    Name() string

    Pre(c Context) (statusCode int, err error)
    Post(c Context) (statusCode int, err error)
    PostErr(c Context)
}

// BaseFilter base filter support default implemention
type BaseFilter struct{}

// Pre execute before proxy
func (f BaseFilter) Pre(c Context) (statusCode int, err error) {
    return http.StatusOK, nil
}

// Post execute after proxy
func (f BaseFilter) Post(c Context) (statusCode int, err error) {
    return http.StatusOK, nil
}

// PostErr execute proxy has errors
func (f BaseFilter) PostErr(c Context) {

}
```

This pkg is in my go app project.

#### load plugin file

```
package proxy

import (
    "errors"
    "plugin"
    "strings"

    "github.com/fagongzi/gateway/pkg/conf"
    "github.com/fagongzi/gateway/pkg/filter"
)

var (
    // ErrKnownFilter known filter error
    ErrKnownFilter = errors.New("unknow filter")
)

const (
    // FilterHTTPAccess access log filter
    FilterHTTPAccess = "HTTP-ACCESS"
    // FilterHeader header filter
    FilterHeader = "HEAD" // process header fiter
    // FilterXForward xforward fiter
    FilterXForward = "XFORWARD"
    // FilterBlackList blacklist filter
    FilterBlackList = "BLACKLIST"
    // FilterWhiteList whitelist filter
    FilterWhiteList = "WHITELIST"
    // FilterAnalysis analysis filter
    FilterAnalysis = "ANALYSIS"
    // FilterRateLimiting limit filter
    FilterRateLimiting = "RATE-LIMITING"
    // FilterCircuitBreake circuit breake filter
    FilterCircuitBreake = "CIRCUIT-BREAKE"
    // FilterValidation validation request filter
    FilterValidation = "VALIDATION"
)

func newFilter(filterSpec *conf.FilterSpec) (filter.Filter, error) {
    if filterSpec.External {
        return newExternalFilter(filterSpec)
    }

    input := strings.ToUpper(filterSpec.Name)

    switch input {
    case FilterHTTPAccess:
        return newAccessFilter(), nil
    case FilterHeader:
        return newHeadersFilter(), nil
    case FilterXForward:
        return newXForwardForFilter(), nil
    case FilterAnalysis:
        return newAnalysisFilter(), nil
    case FilterBlackList:
        return newBlackListFilter(), nil
    case FilterWhiteList:
        return newWhiteListFilter(), nil
    case FilterRateLimiting:
        return newRateLimitingFilter(), nil
    case FilterCircuitBreake:
        return newCircuitBreakeFilter(), nil
    case FilterValidation:
        return newValidationFilter(), nil
    default:
        return nil, ErrKnownFilter
    }
}

func newExternalFilter(filterSpec *conf.FilterSpec) (filter.Filter, error) {
    p, err := plugin.Open(filterSpec.ExternalPluginFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    s, err := p.Lookup("NewExternalFilter")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    sf := s.(func() (filter.Filter, error))
    return sf()
}
```

This is the code of load plugin in my go app project

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/CodisLabs/codis/pkg/utils/log"
    "github.com/fagongzi/gateway/pkg/filter"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

// AccessFilter record the http access log
// log format: $remoteip "$method $path" $code "$agent" $svr $cost
type AccessFilter struct {
}

// NewExternalFilter create a External filter
func NewExternalFilter() (filter.Filter, error) {
    return &AccessFilter{}, nil
}

// Name return name of this filter
func (f *AccessFilter) Name() string {
    return "HTTP-ACCESS"
}

// Pre pre process
func (f *AccessFilter) Pre(c filter.Context) (statusCode int, err error) {
    return 200, nil
}

// Post execute after proxy
func (f *AccessFilter) Post(c filter.Context) (statusCode int, err error) {
    cost := (c.GetStartAt() - c.GetEndAt())

    log.Infof("%s %s \"%s\" %d \"%s\" %s %s",
        GetRealClientIP(c.GetOriginRequestCtx()),
        c.GetOriginRequestCtx().Method(),
        c.GetProxyOuterRequest().RequestURI(),
        c.GetProxyResponse().StatusCode(),
        c.GetOriginRequestCtx().UserAgent(),
        c.GetProxyServerAddr(),
        time.Duration(cost))

    return 200, nil
}

// PostErr post error process
func (f *AccessFilter) PostErr(c filter.Context) {

}

// GetRealClientIP get read client ip
func GetRealClientIP(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) string {
    xforward := ctx.Request.Header.Peek("X-Forwarded-For")
    if nil == xforward {
        return strings.SplitN(ctx.RemoteAddr().String(), ":", 2)[0]
    }

    return strings.SplitN(string(xforward), ",", 2)[0]
}
```

This is the definition of plugin, it's in my plugin project. The plugin project and go app project are different projects.

#### I found errors:

```
panic: interface conversion: plugin.Symbol is func() (filter.Filter, error), not func() (filter.Filter, error)
```

You can find code in this project https://github.com/fagongzi/gateway/tree/go18-plugin-support.

1. `filter.Filter` is in pkg/filter package.
2. `load plugin file` in proxy/factory.go
3. `plugin go file` is in another project.

Comment: Which system are you using? Plugins are currently just supported on Linux. https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#plugin

Answer (score 10):

Custom interfaces work just fine.

But one important thing: you can only [type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) types from values looked up from plugins that are defined **outside** of the plugin (you can't refer types defined in plugins). This also applies to each component of "composite types", for example you can only type assert a function type whose parameter and result types are also defined outside of the plugin.

### 1. With a common package outside of the plugin

One solution is to define the interface in a package outside of the plugin, and both the plugin and your app can import it and refer to it.

Define it in package `filter`:

```
package filter

type Filter interface {
    Name() string
    Age() int
}
```

The plugin is in package `pq` and imports package `filter`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "filter"
)

type plgFilter struct{}

func (plgFilter) Name() string { return "Bob" }
func (plgFilter) Age() int     { return 23 }

func GetFilter() (f filter.Filter, err error) {
    f = plgFilter{}
    fmt.Printf("[plugin GetFilter] Returning filter: %T %v\n", f, f)
    return
}
```

And the main app that also imports (the same) package `filter`, loads the plugin, looks up `GetFilter()`, calls it and also uses the returned `Filter`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "filter"
    "plugin"
)

func main() {
    p, err := plugin.Open("pg/pg.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    GetFilter, err := p.Lookup("GetFilter")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    filter, err := GetFilter.(func() (filter.Filter, error))()
    fmt.Printf("GetFilter result: %T %v %v\n", filter, filter, err)
    fmt.Println("\tName:", filter.Name())
    fmt.Println("\tAge:", filter.Age())
}
```

Output:

```
[plugin GetFilter] Returning filter: main.plgFilter {}
GetFilter result: main.plgFilter {} <nil>
        Name: Bob
        Age: 23
```

### 2. With plugin returning `interface{}`, and interface defined in main app

Another solution is to have the plugin function return a value of type `interface{}`. Your main app can define the interface it expects, and it can use type assertion on the `interface{}` value returned by the plugin.

No `filter` package this time.

The plugin is in package `pq`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type plgFilter struct{}

func (plgFilter) Name() string { return "Bob" }
func (plgFilter) Age() int     { return 23 }

func GetFilterIface() (f interface{}, err error) {
    f = plgFilter{}
    fmt.Printf("[plugin GetFilterIface] Returning filter: %T %v\n", f, f)
    return
}
```

And the main app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "plugin"
)

func main() {
    p, err := plugin.Open("pg/pg.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    GetFilterIface, err := p.Lookup("GetFilterIface")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    filterIface, err := GetFilterIface.(func() (interface{}, error))()
    fmt.Printf("GetFilterIface result: %T %v %v\n", filterIface, filterIface, err)
    myfilter := filterIface.(MyFilter)
    fmt.Println("\tName:", myfilter.Name())
    fmt.Println("\tAge:", myfilter.Age())
}

type MyFilter interface {
    Name() string
    Age() int
}
```

Output:

```
[plugin GetFilterIface] Returning filter: main.plgFilter {}
GetFilterIface result: main.plgFilter {} <nil>
        Name: Bob
        Age: 23
```

Also see related question: [How do Go plugin dependencies work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218472/how-do-go-plugin-dependencies-work/42220856#42220856)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, but it's not  solve the problem, because I described the reasons for unclear. Now i was edit this problem, in fact my solution is like your solution 1.

Comment: @ZhangXu I don't see any `filter` package where you claim there is: https://github.com/fagongzi/gateway/tree/master/pkg. You are somehow mixing the imports / package paths.

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry, it's in the https://github.com/fagongzi/gateway/tree/go18-plugin-support branch. i also open a issue to golang(https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19233), and it's may be a vendor package problem.I will  to verify it when i free

Comment: The plugin code is defined in package main and the plugin is loaded in main. Would this still work if the plugin was loaded from another package than main ? In other words, do the plugin package name need to match the package name where it is loaded (main in the example you gave) ?

Comment: @chmike The plugin must have package `main`, and it can be loaded from anywhere. But a runnable app must also have a package `main`, the `main()` function of package `main` is the entry point of the app. The plugin's `main` and the app's `main` are 2 different, distinct packages.

Comment: @icza I had one last question. In a reddit comment, it was reported that the plugin and main program must be compiled with a same version of go compiler and the same version of imported libraries. Is this really required ?

Comment: @chmike Yes, that's right. Else you'll get an error when opening the plugin.