# golang export all symbols from a plugin

Tags: go, plugins, lookup

Golang plugin pkg only support Lookup a symbol by name.

How can I scan all symbols and its type in a plugin?

https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current plugin API of Go does not support discovering and using unknown plugins. You have to *know* the plugin and *know what to expect* from it (including the types of exported symbols).

One day there might be additions to the API for what you're looking, but for now (Go 1.9.2) you're stuck with [`Plugin.Lookup()`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/#Plugin.Lookup) only.

### "Hack" to peek at exported symbols

A loaded plugin is represented by a value of type [`*plugin.Plugin`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/#Plugin). This is a pointer to a struct which contains the symbol table, but it's not exported. If you want to take a "peek" at what symbols are exported, you may use the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package to print it.

I will use the plugin example from this answer: [go 1.8 plugin use custom interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388090/go-1-8-plugin-use-custom-interface/42389345#42389345), which is:

```
type plgFilter struct{}

func (plgFilter) Name() string { return "Bob" }
func (plgFilter) Age() int     { return 23 }

func GetFilter() (f filter.Filter, err error) {
    f = plgFilter{}
    fmt.Printf("[plugin GetFilter] Returning filter: %T %v\n", f, f)
    return
}
```

It contains a single exported symbol: the `GetFilter` function. Loading and printing the symbol table of this plugin:

```
p, err := plugin.Open("pg/pg.so")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p)
```

We can "observe" the exported `GetFilter` symbol in the output:

```
&{pluginpath:pg loaded:0xc420020120 syms:map[GetFilter:0x7f0a7fddc860]}
```

The associated value for this symbol is a memory address, not really talkative.

But we can do more: we can use package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to print its type after we looked it up:

```
GetFilter, err := p.Lookup("GetFilter")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(GetFilter))
```

And now we'll see:

```
func() (filter.Filter, error)
```

We see it's a function which has 2 return types: `filter.Filter` and `error`.