# Plugin symbol as function return

Tags: go, plugins, interface, symbols

I'm running into a Go behaviour which I don't understand.  My idea is to import a plugin which implements an interface that is out of both packages.  If a struct is returned it works fine, but to be sure it implements the interface, I want to return an interface which fails.

Interface definition:

```golang
package iface

type IPlugin interface{
   SayHello(string)
   SayGoodby(string)
   WhatsYourName() string
}
```

The main program looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "plugin"
    "plugin_test/iface"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

//go:generate go build -buildmode=plugin -o ./pg/test.so ./pg/test.go

func main(){
    path := "pg/test.so"
    plug, err := plugin.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    sym, err := plug.Lookup("Greeter")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var pg iface.IPlugin
    pg, ok := sym.(iface.IPlugin)
    if !ok {
        panic(errors.New("error binding plugin to interface"))
    }

    fmt.Printf("You're now connected to: %s \n", pg.WhatsYourName())
    pg.SayHello("user")
    pg.SayGoodby("user")
}
```

The plugin (stored in pg/test.go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "plugin_test/iface"
)

type testpl struct {}

func(pl testpl) SayHello(s string){
    fmt.Printf("Plugin says hello to %s \n", s)
}
func(pl testpl) SayGoodby(s string){
    fmt.Printf("Plugin says goodby to %s \n", s)
}
func(pl testpl) WhatsYourName() string{
    return "my name is Test-Plugin"
}

/* This function works */
func getPlugin() testpl{
    return testpl{}
}

/* This function doesn't work */
func getPlugin() iface.IPlugin{
    return testpl{}
}

/* This function also doesn't work */
func getPlugin() interface{}{
    return testpl{}
}

var Greeter = getPlugin()
```

I tried every `getPlugin` function on its own.

The function returning `testpl` prints the expected output:

```
You're now connected to: my name is Test-Plugin
Plugin says hello to user
Plugin says goodby to user
```

The other functions end on `sym.(iface.IPlugin)`

```
panic: error binding plugin to interface

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/../../../main.go:27 +0x343
exit status 2
```

Can someone explain why this isn't possible? Wouldn't it be easier to create a plugin if it did't let you build your plugin in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is possible, but there is something in the background that prevents it from working.

This is namely that you want to lookup a *variable* named `Greeter` from the plugin. [`Plugin.Lookup()`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/#Plugin.Lookup) will return a pointer to this variable! If it wouldn't, you could only inspect its value, but you couldn't change it.

You can verify this by simply printing the type of the value stored in `sym`:

```
fmt.Printf("%T\n", sym)
```

In your first case `func getPlugin() testpl`, output will be:

```
*main.testpl
```

In your second case `func getPlugin() iface.IPlugin`, output will be:

```
*iface.IPlugin
```

(Yes, it's a pointer to an interface!)

In your third case `func getPlugin() interface{}`, output will be:

```
*interface {}
```

So your first example works because the value stored in `sym` is of type `*main.testpl`, which also implements `iface.IPlugin` (because `main.testpl` implements it, so does the pointer type).

Back to your 2nd example: `func getPlugin() iface.IPlugin`

The value stored in `sym` is of type `*iface.IPlugin`. A value of pointer type to interface never satisfies any interfaces (except the empty interface), so attempting to type-assert `iface.IPlugin` from a value of type `*iface.IPlugin` will never succeed. You have to type assert `*iface.IPlugin` type, which you can dereference after to obtain a value of type `iface.IPlugin`. It could look like this:

```
pgPtr, ok := sym.(*iface.IPlugin)
if !ok {
    panic(errors.New("error binding plugin to interface"))
}
pg := *pgPtr
```

And now everything works as expected!

To avoid such hassle and confusion, you may implement your plugin to expose a *function* which returns you the `Greeter`:

```
func Greeter() iface.IPlugin { return testpl{} }
```

And then get rid of the `Greeter` global var of course. If you do this, you may lookup the `Greeter` symbol which will be of type:

```
func() iface.IPlugin
```

The difference is that looking up a function does not require the `plugin` package to return a pointer to the value, while in case of a variable it does. A simple function type, no pointer-to-interface-kung-fu. Using it to obtain the greeter would be:

```
Greeter, err := p.Lookup("Greeter")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
greeterFunc, ok := GetFilter.(func() iface.IPlugin)
if !ok {
    panic(errors.New("not of expected type"))
}
greeter := greeterFunc()

// And using it:
fmt.Printf("You're now connected to: %s \n", greeter.WhatsYourName())
greeter.SayHello("user")
greeter.SayGoodby("user")
```

See related / similar question: [go 1.8 plugin use custom interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388090/go-1-8-plugin-use-custom-interface/42389345#42389345)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.
The solution to return by a public-function seems much prettier than the global var. I will use this method in the future.