plugin implementation
Trying to implement Go plugin.
Here's my plugin code
package main

import (
    "errors"
)

// Config represents configuration data.
type Config struct {
    Path string
}

// Message represents a message.
type Message struct {
    EventMessage string
}

// Assessment represents an assessment.
type Assessment struct {
    AtRisk bool
}

// RulePlugin represents a plugin that implements the Plugin interface.
type rulePlugin struct {
}

// Init initializes the plugin with the provided configuration.
func (p *rulePlugin) Init(config *Config) error {
    if config == nil {
        return errors.New("config is nil")
    }
    // Additional initialization logic can go here if needed
    return nil
}

// ProcessMessage processes the message and returns an assessment.
func (p *rulePlugin) ProcessMessage(message *Message) (*Assessment, error) {
    if message == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("message is nil")
    }
    // Example assessment logic
    atRisk := len(message.EventMessage) > 10
    return &Assessment{AtRisk: atRisk}, nil
}

// exported
var Plugin *rulePlugin


Plugin build command:
go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -buildmode=plugin -o rulePlugin.so rulePlugin.go
rulePlugin.so built successfully!
Here's my code to invoke Plugin

//go:build exclude

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "plugin"
)

// Plugin defines the interface for a plugin.
type Plugin interface {
    Init(config *Config) error
    ProcessMessage(message *Message) (*Assessment, error)
}

// Config represents configuration data.
type Config struct {
    Path string
}

// Message represents a message.
type Message struct {
    EventMessage string
}

// Assessment represents an assessment.
type Assessment struct {
    AtRisk bool
}

func main() {
    // Load the plugin
    p, err := plugin.Open("rulePlugin.so")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading plugin:", err)
        return
    }

    // Lookup the symbol representing the Plugin interface
    symPlugin, err := p.Lookup("Plugin")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error looking up Plugin symbol:", err)
        return
    }

    // Assert that the symbol implements the Plugin interface
    var rulePlugin Plugin
    rulePlugin, ok := symPlugin.(Plugin)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Plugin does not implement Plugin interface")
        return
    }

    // Initialize the plugin with some configuration
    config := &Config{Path: "/some/path"}
    if err := rulePlugin.Init(config); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error initializing plugin:", err)
        return
    }

    // Create a sample message
    message := &Message{EventMessage: "This is a test message"}

    // Process the message using the plugin
    assessment, err := rulePlugin.ProcessMessage(message)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error processing message:", err)
        return
    }

    // Print the assessment result
    fmt.Println("Assessment result:", assessment.AtRisk)
}

Trying to execute the above code like:
go run rulePlugintest.go
Plugin does not implement Plugin interface
I do not understand whats going on here and what I am missing.
I have checked many samples, for example this one:  https://github.com/huantt/golang-plugin-examle/blob/main/main.go which executes great. Not sure what I am missing in my implementation, any ideas would be appreciated.

I think you're missing that the docs state: A Symbol is a pointer to a variable or function., so symPlugin is a **rulePlugin (just remove the , ok from the assertion and the panic will tell you the type you have)

Thank you! made the changes as suggested and now getting error:
panic: interface conversion: **main.rulePlugin is not main.Plugin: missing method Init
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
rulePlugintest.go:74 +0x318
exit status 2

This solved my problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388090/go-1-8-plugin-use-custom-interface/42389345#42389345
