# Can golang plugins be used for factory functions?

Tags: go, plugins

I have the following code in a golang plugin module:

plug.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

var (
    Thing        = New("first thing")
    ThingFactory = thingFactory{}
)

type thing struct {
    i int
    s string
}

func New(s string) thing {
    return thing{s: s}
}

func (t *thing) Say() string {
    t.i++
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s - %d", t.s, t.i)
}

type thingFactory struct{}

func (t thingFactory) Make(s string) thing {
    return New(s)
}
```

it is compiled as a .so object and used in another program:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "plugin"
)

func main() {
    p, err := plugin.Open("../plug/plug.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    symbol, err := p.Lookup("Thing")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    thing := symbol.(Sayer)
    fmt.Println(thing.Say())

    symbol, err = p.Lookup("ThingFactory") // <-problems start here
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    factory := symbol.(GetSayer)

    madeThing := factory.Make("how about me?")
    fmt.Println(madeThing.Say())
    fmt.Println(madeThing.Say())
}

type Sayer interface {
    Say() string
}

type GetSayer interface {
    Make(string) Sayer
}
```

I'm able to lookup the `Thing`, and call `Say()` on it, but the second interface conversion panics:

`first thing - 1
panic: interface conversion: *main.thingFactory is not main.GetSayer: missing method Make`

even though the runtime recognizes the first symbol as a `Sayer` it doesn't recognize that `thingFactory` obviously has a Make() method, which should return something that is also a Sayer.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that in your plugin `thingFactory` (more precicely `*thingfactory`) does not have a method described in your main app's `GetSayer` interface:

```
Make(string) Sayer
```

You have:

```
Make(string) thing
```

So (first) you have to change `thingFactory.Make()` to this:

```
type Sayer interface {
    Say() string
}

func (t thingFactory) Make(s string) Sayer {
    th := New(s)
    return &th
}
```

After this it still won't work. And the reason for this is because the plugin's `Sayer` type is not identical to your main app's `Sayer` type. But they must be the same in order to implement your main app's `GetSayer` interface.

One solution is to "outsource" the `Sayer` interface to its own package, and use this common, shared package both in the plugin and in the main app.

Let's create a new package, call it `subplay`:

```
package subplay

type Sayer interface {
    Say() string
}
```

Import this package and use it in the plugin:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/to/subplay"
)

var (
    Thing        = New("first thing")
    ThingFactory = thingFactory{}
)

type thing struct {
    i int
    s string
}

func New(s string) thing {
    return thing{s: s}
}

func (t *thing) Say() string {
    t.i++
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s - %d", t.s, t.i)
}

type thingFactory struct{}

func (t thingFactory) Make(s string) subplay.Sayer {
    th := New(s)
    return &th
}
```

And also import and use it in the main app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/to/subplay"
    "plugin"
)

func main() {
    p, err := plugin.Open("../plug/plug.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    symbol, err := p.Lookup("Thing")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    thing := symbol.(subplay.Sayer)
    fmt.Println(thing.Say())

    symbol, err = p.Lookup("ThingFactory")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    factory := symbol.(GetSayer)

    madeThing := factory.Make("how about me?")
    fmt.Println(madeThing.Say())
    fmt.Println(madeThing.Say())
}

type GetSayer interface {
    Make(string) subplay.Sayer
}
```

Now it will work, and output will be:

```
first thing - 1
how about me? - 1
how about me? - 2
```

See related questions:

[go 1.8 plugin use custom interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388090/go-1-8-plugin-use-custom-interface/42389345#42389345)

[How do Go plugin dependencies work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218472/how-do-go-plugin-dependencies-work/42220856#42220856)

Comment: thanks - I was sure it _should_ be possible, but the third package "outsourcing" was non obvious.  I did some searching, but unfortunately there still isn't a ton of plugin use in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin Make method should return a Sayer object not thing

```
type Sayer interface {
    Say() string
}
func (t *thingFactory) Make(s string) Sayer {
    return New(s)
}
```

Comment: I didn't assert it was `Sayer` - I asserted `GetSayer` - the factory type. The interface you defined as `Factory` is identical to the interface I defined, only I called it `GetSayer`.  Also, putting another interface in the plugin code, means that the interface conversion results in pointer to interface problems.

Comment: @domoarigato the signature of GetSayer and plugin's Make method are different. Change Plugin method to return Sayer

Comment: That's the thing, they actually aren't different.  `thingFactory` has a `Make` method, which returns a `thing`, which the compiler recognizes is a `Sayer`, therefore `thingFactory` implements `GetSayer`.  The `Sayer` interface is in the host code, not the plugin Code, and putting a different interface, which also happens to be called `Sayer` in the plugin code, and returning it doesn't change anything about the situation (I did try it) except that it does cause issues with *interface in the type conversion.

Comment: Tried it, sorry, but it doesn't work. It still doesn't recognize that plugin.thingFactory is host.GetSayer: missing method Make - same problem.