# Cast Method with return value to a method with interface{}

Tags: go, plugins

I have a plugin that defines following struct:

```
type foo struct {
    counter int64
}

type Plugin struct {}

func (p *Plugin) Do() *foo {
    // Do something
    return &foo{123}
}
```

In my main application, I need to cast the plugin to an interface in order to be able to use `Do()`. At this moment I do not care about the returned value (pointer to a `foo` struct), but it would be nice to have it.

Question, how do I cast and define a valid interface, if I do not have access to the `foo` struct? I tried the following options:

```
type MyFoo struct {
    counter int64
}

type PluginInterface interface {
    Do() *MyFoo
}

type PluginInterface2 interface {
    Do() interface{}
}

func main() {
    plugin := Plugin{} // this would be code that loads bar as an interface {} from the plugin
    do(&plugin)

}

func do(plugin interface{}) {
    _, ok := plugin.(PluginInterface)
    fmt.Println("OK with own Struct?", ok) // false
    _, ok2 := plugin.(PluginInterface2)
    fmt.Println("OK with generic interface?", ok2) // false
}
```

However, the cast to `PluginInterface` and `PluginInterface2` fails. Obviously, if I change  the method definition of `Do()` in the plugin to return a generic `interface{}`, then `PluginInterface2` cast would succeed.

Example code: https://play.golang.org/p/rB5zZVChSpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Change signature of `Plugin.Do()` to return a value of type defined *outside* of the plugin (e.g. defined in a 3rd package used by both your app and the plugin), or to return e.g. `interface{}`.

See related questions:

- [go 1.8 plugin use custom interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388090/go-1-8-plugin-use-custom-interface/42389345#42389345)
- [Is it possible to share a custom data type between a go plugin and an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194888/is-it-possible-to-share-a-custom-data-type-between-a-go-plugin-and-an-applicatio/50495240#50495240)
- [Can golang plugins be used for factory functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904995/can-golang-plugins-be-used-for-factory-functions/53906730#53906730)

If you can't change the plugin, you may use reflection to call the method. Example calling the [`Time.Hour()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Hour) method:

```
var x interface{} = time.Date(2019, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
hour := v.MethodByName("Hour")
results := hour.Call(nil)
fmt.Println(results[0])
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5oZiOop-7ib)):

```
14
```